# ¿Existe alguna diferencia contextual entre usar "para" y "de" en "Pila para/de reloj"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, preposiciones

He estado leyendo un poco y tengo esta duda en el uso de ambas preposiciones (si es que eso es lo que son).

¿El uso de una u otra en la frase propuesta ("Pila para/de reloj") implica alguna diferencia en el significado de la frase misma?

Es confuso porque en el inglés simplemente diría "watch battery" sin la presencia de alguna preposición, cosa que sí hay que hacer en español.

Answer (score 3):

Vamos, diferencia hay, pero no creo que sea importante.

En el caso de usar *para*, referimos al hecho de que la pila está destinada al reloj.

En el caso de emplear *de*, referimos al hecho de que bien la pila pertenece al reloj (*de* posesivo) bien la naturaleza de pila es de tipo reloj (un sustantivo que modifica otro).

Tal vez haya algún momento en que esta diferencia sea importante pero a usos cotidianos, son iguales, y el uso popular regirá la preposición por que un hablante opta.